# Types mismatch, should I necessarily use liftIO?

Tags: haskell, servant

I want to perform a delete operation in Servant and return an error or (). Here's my code:

```
del :: Int -> ExceptT ServantErr IO ()
del myId = liftIO $ do
  cn <- getConnection
  a <- execute cn "delete from table1 where id = ?" [myId]
  case a of
    1 -> return ()
    _ -> throwE err503 --compile error
```

The error is:

```
  Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’
                with actual type ‘ExceptT ServantErr m0 a0’
    In the expression: throwE err503
    In a case alternative: _ -> throwE err503
```

I'd prefer not to use liftIO before each expression if possible:

```
del myId =  do
  cn <- liftIO getConnection
  a <- liftIO $ execute cn "delete from table1 where id = ?" [myId]
  case a of
    1 -> return ()
    _ -> throwE err503
```

How can I return an error then?

Answer (score 7):

I think you won't be able to avoid it.  Everthing in a do-block must be in the same monad, so with the initial

```
 del :: Int -> ExceptT ServantErr IO ()
 del myId = liftIO $ do ...
```

every line must be in `IO`. But you can rearrange things in various ways, e.g. with a subordinate IO block, where some things come together:

```
 del myId = do
   a <- liftIO $ do 
     cn <- getConnection
     execute cn "delete from table1 where id = ?" [myId]
   case a of
     1 -> return ()
     _ -> throwE err503
```

or, with `Control.Monad.unless`, say:

```
del myId = do
  a <- liftIO $ do 
     cn <- getConnection
     execute cn "delete from table1 where id = ?" [myId]
  unless (a == 1) $ throwE err503
```

and any number of other ways. You don't say which `getConnection` and `execute` you are using, but are you sure they are not already `MonadIO m => m ..`? In which case you can drop the `liftIO` after all?